# Ways to destroy a Square Matrix

Tags: mathematics, optimization, game

Sherlock is solving a case where he came across a puzzle. Suppose you are given a square matrix of size $N$, and a gun with Power $F$. Every cell in the matrix is filled with some number, $x$ (thickness or toughness of the cell), such that $1 < x < F$.  Not every cell will contain the same value of $x$

Sherlock can shoot the matrix from UP, DOWN, LEFT, or RIGHT to destroy cells. Each shot destroys cells in a line, until the sum thickness of the cells is $>F$, and each cell must be destroyed outright, in a single shot.

Here is the catch! He has to destroy the matrix in strictly less than $M$ shots! Here $M = min(A, B)$, where $A$ is the number of shots required to destroy the matrix by using only horizontal (LEFT or RIGHT) shots, and $B$ is the number of shots required to destroy the matrix by using only vertical (UP and DOWN) shots.

What is the optimal strategy for Sherlock to take to destroy the matrix in $O<M$ shots?

---

Example:  $N=3$, $F=5$

```
[2][2][2]
[2][3][2]
[2][2][2]
```

$A=6$, $B=6$, $M=6$

```
►[X][X][2]   [ ][ ][2]   [ ][ ][2]
 [2][3][2]  ►[X][X][2]   [ ][ ][2]
 [2][2][2]   [2][2][2]  ►[X][X][2]


►[ ][ ][X]   [ ][ ][ ]   [ ][ ][ ]
 [ ][ ][2]  ►[ ][ ][X]   [ ][ ][ ]
 [ ][ ][2]   [ ][ ][2]  ►[ ][ ][X]
```

$O=5$

```
                    ▼              
►[X][X][2]   [ ][ ][X]   [ ][ ][ ] 
 [2][3][2]   [2][3][X]   [2][3][ ] 
 [2][2][2]   [2][2][2]   [2][X][X]◄

                 ▼       
 [ ][ ][ ]   [ ][ ][ ]   
 [X][3][ ]  ►[ ][X][ ]◄  
 [X][ ][ ]   [ ][ ][ ]   
  ▲              ▲
```

NOTE: All the values of cells will never be >F/2 and the sum entries in each row or column >=F. O is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: The puzzle is about an _arbitrary_ matrix but you say "you need to show ... the moves". Are you looking for a description of how to determine those moves, given the matrix?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, I am looking at how to determine the moves.

Comment: Must cells destroyed outright (in one shot), or can they be weakened?  i.e. if `F=4`, would shooting the row  `[2][3][3]` from the left take 2 shots (`[2][3][3]`►`[0][1][3]`►`[0][0][0]`) or 3 shots (`[2][3][3]`►`[0][3][3]`►`[0][0][3]`►`[0][0][0]`)?  "He can only destroy the cells in one shot" is ambiguous on that count, since it is talking about how each shot can destroy multiple cells.

Comment: @Chronocidal They cannot be weakened. If F=4, and if the matrix is [2][3][3] then in 1st shot it will be [0][3][3] as the sum of 2+3 > F. Then it will be [0][0][3] as 3+3 > F. then [0][0][0] So total 3 shots.

Comment: It doesn't seem like O is guaranteed to exist. For example, if the sum of entries in each row is < F then I think the best we can do is A.

Comment: Similarly, if all the cells have values $>F/2$, then every shot always clears exactly 1 cell and $M=A=B=n^2$, and there is no way to get $O<M$.

Comment: @hexomino Agreed.  While we would need OP to agree, I think removing that constraint (either making it instead to just *minimise* `O`, or add "or prove that `M` is the optimum solution") is needed.  (Also, asking for a program to output an optimal solution for a given Array and `F` might be an interesting question for [codegolf.se])

Comment: @Chronocidal thanks for editing the question with an example to it

Comment: I upvoted the puzzle because the idea is fun, but hexomino and Jaap Scherphuis definitely both have a point that needs to be addressed before one can make anything from this.

Comment: O is guaranteed to exist for some very specific matrices only. Are we supposed to work out the rule for identifying such matrices too? Seems like it might be a computationally hard problem.

Comment: This problem feels very much from some sort of programming contest where you'd need to write code to solve various given testcases. Is there a source for this question?

Comment: Well I can give you a lower bound on the number of moves. It is ceiling(S/F), where S is the sum of all cell values.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a variation on a [Bin-Packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) or [Guillotine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillotine_problem) problem...

I am going to start with a fairly naïve algorithm, which is far from optimal - but hopefully gives other people something to build from.

> For every Row and Column, write down **how many cells** will be destroyed by shooting it from either end, and **What they sum to**.
>
>  Start with the shot which destroys the highest number of cells.
>
>  - In case of a draw, choose the shot with the highest Sum destroyed
>
>    - If this is *also* a draw, start with  the clockwise-most shot on the side of the matrix clockwise from the last shot taken, and move counter-clockwise until you reach a drawing shot
>
>      (If no shot has yet been taken, start at the top-left horizontal shot)
>
>  Repeat until all cells have been destroyed

Reasoning:

> To Minimise $O$, we need to destroy *as many cells* as we can with each shot.  We also want to try to minimise "unused" power from each shot

How I know this is not an optimal solution:

> Sometimes, and optimal solution many require destroying a *short* line to open up a *long* liner:
>   Example, $F=5$
>   Algorithm, 13 shots
>    `.                       ▼                                          .`
>    `[4][4][2][1]  [4][4][2][X]  [4][4][2][ ]  [4][4][2][ ]  [4][4][2][ ]`
>    `[4][4][1][4]  [4][4][1][X]  [4][4][1][ ]  [4][X][X][ ]  [4][ ][ ][ ]`
>    `[4][4][4][2]  [4][4][4][2]  [4][4][4][X]  [4][4][4][ ]  [4][4][4][ ]`
>    `[4][4][2][2]  [4][4][2][2]  [4][4][2][X]  [4][4][2][ ]  [4][4][2][ ]`
>    `.                                     ▲                            .`
>  3 shots taken.  Remaining 10 cells require 1 shot each
>
>
>  No Algorithm, 12 shots:
>    `.                                                                  .`
>    `[4][4][2][1]  [4][4][2][1]  [4][4][2][X]  [4][4][2][ ]  [4][4][X][ ]`
>    `[4][4][1][4]  [4][4][X][X]◄ [4][4][ ][ ]  [4][X][ ][ ]  [4][4][ ][ ]`
>    `[4][4][4][2]  [4][4][4][2]  [4][4][4][X]  [4][4][X][ ]◄ [4][4][ ][ ]`
>    `[4][4][2][2]  [4][4][2][2]  [4][4][2][X]  [4][4][2][ ]  [4][4][X][ ]`
>    `.                                     ▲                        ▲   .`
>    `[4][4][ ][ ]`
>    `[4][4][ ][ ]`
>    `[4][4][ ][ ]`
>    `[4][4][ ][ ]`  4 shots taken, remaining 8 cells require 1 shot each